# Why doesn't the NavigationTitles appear when calling ContentView not from the main struct

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

This the main struct for my app, in a file called `GitaApp.swift`:

```swift
@main
struct GitaApp: App {
    @AppStorage("test_launchedBefore") var launched = false
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if launched == true {
                ContentView()
            } else {
                welcome()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When `launched` is true, it works well, and the content pops up:

[image: ![enter image description here]

When `launched` is false, it runs a struct in a file called `Welcome.swift`. It goes through a 2 structs, starting at the `welcome` struct and ending at the ending struct:

```swift
struct welcome: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink("Let's set up!", destination: ending())
        }
    }
}

struct ending: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink("Let's go!", destination:
            ContentView() // <-- goes to ContentView
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
        )
    }
}
```

And this appears:

[image: ![enter image description here]

The title disappears, and this happens to every tab and view in ContentView file. Why does this happen? I couldn't find anything about it anywhere.

My ContentView is like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            HomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "house")
                    Text("Home")
                }
            
            ... // <-- different tabs
        }
    }
}
```

And as a example, this is my `HomeView`, the first tab:

```swift
struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {

            Text("Hi").font(.largeTitle)

        .navigationTitle("Home")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This needs a [mre]. You haven't shown where you've set the title for anything or how the `TabView` or `NavigationStack` work/interact, so it's not possible to debug.

Comment: @jnpdx, yes sorry forgot to add some code for that

Comment: Is this really a _minimal_ example? Does the `NetworkMonitor` need to be there for the problem to happen? Also, no one can run your code yet. Again, consider adding a [mre].

Comment: @jnpdx, sorry, but I edited the post and added code for the startup `welcome` structs. What other code do I should I add?

Comment: I tested if I'm able to reproduce the issue with the code provided here and I can reproduce the problem successfully.

Comment: There is no title on the `welcome` screen because you have not added a `navigationTitle ` to it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the screen at `HomeView` doesn't have the title appear.

Comment: The problem is likely that you have a `TabView` embedded in the middle of a `NavigationStack`. Typically, `TabView` is the top level component and a `NavigationStack` is used on each one of the tabs

Comment: Thank you @jnpdx, that's correct. I decided to use `fullScreenCover` to present `ContentView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [jnpdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76846910/why-doesnt-the-navigationtitles-appear-when-calling-contentview-not-from-the-ma/76847325#comment135475803_76846910), I figured out the problem is that the `TabView` is supposed to be the root and a NavigationStack at the root doesn't work. I couldn't find a easy way to move to another except for `.fullScreenCover`, so I did it like this:

```swift
struct ending: View {
    @State private var isPresented = false
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            isPresented.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("Let's go!")
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            ContentView()
        }     // <--- fullScreenCover to present ContentView
    }
}
```